# Record raw http requests in weblogic

Tags: weblogic, soap, java

We are running a java ee application on weblogic 12.1 that has a soap messaging component. We are having trouble with our soap responses and want to get more details so we can figure out exactly what is going wrong.

The problem is the raw http is not visible in the java component so it is difficult to figure out what is going wrong.

Is there away to get weblogic to log the raw http request/response including content and headers?

Note: technically it is a https request/response, we want to view it after it has been decrypted.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a known key and have access to them, wireshark can [decrypt the traffic](http://blogs.technet.com/b/nettracer/archive/2010/10/01/how-to-decrypt-an-ssl-or-tls-session-by-using-wireshark.aspx) using the provided key, so you could use a standard packet capture tool to capture them (encrypted), and then just decrypt them for viewing

Comment: Thanks. I've used wire shark on windows before, but unfortunately a. this is a Linux server b. we cannot install software

So I need a way to do it either in weblogic or in java

Comment: @TheCatWhisperer wireshark is just for viewing, libpcap can capture packets on linux and then they can be exported to windows for viewing - unfortunately I am not an expert in weblogic, so I don't have any answers in that/the java layer - even if you don't have access to the machine, could you set up a proxy to capture the traffic? or perhaps just do it on the client?

Comment: Nope, government controlled server :(

Comment: @TheCatWhisperer Any chance you could set it up / deploy on another server for development purposes? As much as I would love to hear the java/weblogic solution, I am not sure there is any outside of re-creating the HTTP protocol from scratch in Java